# SQL Server Database Copy Issue

Tags: sql-server

I want to copy some tables from my DB1 to my DB2. The table structures in DB1 are the same as the table structures in DB2 but data in the tables are different. I want to copy tables from DB1 to DB2 but to keep old tables and data on DB2. How can I do this with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio? I tried to right click and do the export but it looks like that will just copy all data from DB1 to DB2 and I do not want that. If anyone can help with this please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Have you tried exporting the insert statement? How did you try to export? can you please provide some examples of data and unwanted results so the community can help you further?

Comment: Sounds like you just need to do an `INSERT INTO` statement... [INSERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: If the tables have the same name on both servers, then are you going to put them in a different schema on DB2? Are you going to put them in the same schema, but rename the tables on DB2?

Comment: " that will just copy all data from DB1 to DB2 and I do not want that" _What do you want?_ Your question says you want to copy data then you say you don't. What do you want to do?